# не получается разархивировать в CentOS

Tags: centos, centos7, gzip, tar

не получается разархивировать
`tar xzvf jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
пишет tar: дл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]я старой опции f нужно указать аргумент.

Comment: видимо, внутри файла `jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` хранится что-то «не то». посмотрите: `$ file jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Comment: пишет: **html document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminator** скачивал файл ``wget https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/16.0.2%2B7/d4a915d82b4c4fbb9bde534da945d746/jdk-16.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz``

Comment: вот то, что по ссылке (веб-страница с текстом ошибки) у вас в файле и сохранено. скачивайте вручную и копируйте файл куда надо. // или скачивайте, [добавив http-заголовок](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959815/4827341), который сервер от вас хочет.

Comment: спасибо большое, получилось